# How to prevent saving empty data into Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to prevent my app from saving empty data. Eg, I forgot to key the Barcode Number, The blank data won't be sent to the firebase. Currently, if I forgot to key the Barcode Number the barcode number a blank data will be saved into my database, which I do not want.

Here is my Code:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String B=et7.getText().toString();
            String PN=et8.getText().toString();
            String E=et9.getText().toString();
            String D=et10.getText().toString();
            String Q=et11.getText().toString();
            String name=et20.getText().toString();
            String number=et21.getText().toString();
            String email=et22.getText().toString();
            Product PO=new Product(B,PN,E,D,Q,name,number,email);
           // reference.child(B).setValue(PO);
            reference.push().setValue(PO);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Successfully Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(AddProduct.this, Inventory.class));
        }
```

Comment: check the strings `B`; `PN` etc before pushing into `Firebase`. Always remember, validations are needed to be done on your end. `Firebase` will not do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check, before sending data to firebase that all fields are not empty.

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String B=et7.getText().toString();
        String PN=et8.getText().toString();
        String E=et9.getText().toString();
        String D=et10.getText().toString();
        String Q=et11.getText().toString();
        String name=et20.getText().toString();
        String number=et21.getText().toString();
        String email=et22.getText().toString();
        if(B.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(PN.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(EB.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(DQ.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(number.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(email.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Name is mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else{
        Product PO=new Product(B,PN,E,D,Q,name,number,email);
       // reference.child(B).setValue(PO);
        reference.push().setValue(PO);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Successfully Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(AddProduct.this, Inventory.class));
      }
    }
```

I think you were searching for this.

Comment: @PeterHaddad that's not wrong because when you will focus on the Logic you will understand that 
The very first we are taking text from text field(EditText). after that, I am checking if any variable is empty then show Toast and get out of if-else.
If all fields are not empty then it will reach to else statement and submit data .

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad
Now I found that I forgot to add else with if

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

inside onClick after declaring the variables do this:

```
 String B=et7.getText().toString();
if(B.isEmpty()){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return;
 }
```

This way it wont be saved if it is empty in the database.

Or you can do this:

```
if(B.isEmpty()){
 //don't save
   }
  else{
    reference.child(B).setValue(PO);
   }
```